# Minimal Linux kernel options to enable hid input

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux, hid

I need to handle a HID device (a barcode reader) with a custom Linux (v5.8).

I have a modulerized kernel which works as expected with other USB peripherals (storage and serial are known to work), but I seem unable to scan this device.

Plugging it into a desktop (Linux Mint "Ulyana", if it matters) I get a normal enumeration:

```
[525428.367216] usb 1-11: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[525428.517071] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e0, idProduct=1200, bcdDevice= 1.00
[525428.517077] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[525428.517080] usb 1-11: Product: Symbol Bar Code Scanner
[525428.517083] usb 1-11: Manufacturer: Symbol Technologies, Inc, 2008
[525428.517086] usb 1-11: SerialNumber: S/N:0641F625A3A943949AF00BAB171ABFE2 Rev:PAACFS00-001-R023
[525428.519932] input: Symbol Technologies, Inc, 2008 Symbol Bar Code Scanner as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/0003:05E0:1200.0005/input/input32
[525428.579736] hid-generic 0003:05E0:1200.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Symbol Technologies, Inc, 2008 Symbol Bar Code Scanner] on usb-0000:00:14.0-11/input0
```

While on my target I see no sign of the new peripheral; `lsusb` displays just the root HUB even when I manually `modprobe` (what I think are) the relevant modules:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by    Not tainted
usbhid                 23296  0 
usbmon                 19424  0 
mt7603e                38048  0 
mt76                   31648  1 mt7603e
mac80211              380000  2 mt7603e,mt76
sha256_generic          2240  0 
libsha256               8480  1 sha256_generic
ehci_platform           4704  0 
cfg80211              236736  3 mt7603e,mt76,mac80211
ehci_hcd               37936  1 ehci_platform
rfkill                  8544  1 cfg80211
usbcore               143456  4 usbhid,usbmon,ehci_platform,ehci_hcd
libarc4                  832  1 mac80211
mtk_eth                30208  0 
usb_common              2768  3 usbmon,ehci_platform,usbcore
```

I am obviously missing something, but I seem unable to understand what.
What should I cross-check?

Note: please feel free to ask for relevant details, I did not put too many things here just to avoid cluttering but I'm fully prepared to give all info deemed useful.

Comment: USB bar code scanners generally look like keyboards, which don't usually create device nodes.

Comment: @stark Confirmed. This scanner works in "keyboard emulation mode". It's unclear to me what You are trying to say; could You elaborate, please? with desktop I see: "Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05e0:1200 Symbol Technologies Bar Code Scanner" while on target I see nothing and scanner does *not* work, not even the startup beep, as if not powered on at all.

Comment: Are you sure your target provides enough power?

Comment: @stark: Yes. This same hardware works with an ancient kernel version (3.18+tons of vendor patches). I am trying to move to a modern build (for unrelated issues) and this is one of the last things remaining to "port". Unfortunately kernel config changed enough to make it difficult to compare.

Comment: Can you try plugging something else in, or is it hard-wired?

Comment: xhci is the USB 3.0 driver, I'm guessing some compatibility issue with your USB port, since the ehci driver (USB 2.0) is loaded, but not xhci.

Comment: On a PC, low- and full-speed (USB 1.1) devices plugged into a USB 2.0 port get routed by a "rate-matching hub" to either OHCI or UHCI HCD, and high-speed (USB 2.0) devices get routed to EHCI HCD. Is there anything equivalent to that in your hardware?

Comment: @IanAbbott: It's a normal USB-A female. I can plug in whatever. Memory stick (USB-storage) and serial are known to work with no problems. Plugging in a real keyboard exhibits the same behavior (apparently not plugged in; capslock/numlock leds not working). One more data point: after I inserted the keyboard, USB-stick was *not* recognized anymore till next reboot. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @IanAbbott: my hardware (based on MT7628) has a single USB 2.0 (EHCI) port. Device Tree (ralink/vocore2.dts in-tree) says: "usb_phy: usb-phy@10120000 {                compatible = "mediatek,mt7628-usbphy"; ...}" and "ehci@101c0000 { compatible = "generic-ehci"; reg = <0x101c0000 0x1000>; phys = <&usb_phy>; phy-names = "usb"; ...}".

Comment: So you reckon it works with USB serial adaptors? Those are usually full-speed devices like your bar-code scanner, I think.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes. USB is generally working. I am, very likely, just missing some Kernel CONFIG_<something> setting, but I'm unable to understand what. My problem is the USB-input subsystem. Other systems seem to work ok.

Comment: It's puzzling that lsusb doesn't show the device. Does dmesg show anything when the device is plugged in?

Comment: @IanAbbott: no, dmesg doesn't seem to notice at all. However I *seem* to have found the culprit. The not-working peripherals are all and only the ones actually running low-speed. In this case USB mandates handling connection to a different controller (low speed). Most likely that's the one not working, for some reason. I'm investigating this now. Any hint would be very welcome.

Comment: @ZioByte Some EHCI host controllers have a "transaction translator" to support low-speed and full-speed devices directly, but yours doesn't. Most EHCI host controllers only handle high-speed (480 Mbit/s) devices and hand off low-speed and full-speed devices to another controller as you mentioned. From the output you posted from the desktop machine, your scanner seems to be a "full-speed" (12 Mbit/s) device rather than a "low-speed" (1.5Mbit/s).

Comment: Not sure if it's the same device, but OpenWrt's DTS stuff for VoCore2 seems to include an OHCI host controller in addition to the EHCI controller. See https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=tree;f=target/linux/ramips/dts .  Its DTS files for vocore2 include "mt7628an.dtsi" which has both EHCI and OHCI controllers.

Comment: @IanAbbott: thanks Ian, I already saw that and I'm trying to see if this saves my day (compiling now). Problem is addresses in OpenWRT DT OHCI controller do *not* appear in MT7628 Programming Manual :/ I hope they know what they're doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out OHCI driver is *needed* to handle low speed peripherals even if they're connected to USB2 (EHCI) controller.

Actually MT7628 has a "secondary" OHCI controller not even advertised in Data Sheet.

This means that, on top of selecting `CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=m` and `CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD_PLATFORM=m` also the following patch is needed:

```
diff --git a/arch/mips/boot/dts/ralink/mt7628a.dtsi b/arch/mips/boot/dts/ralink/mt7628a.dtsi
index bf6b6a459bd6..b4ac008fdfdf 100644
--- a/arch/mips/boot/dts/ralink/mt7628a.dtsi
+++ b/arch/mips/boot/dts/ralink/mt7628a.dtsi
@@ -323,6 +323,17 @@ ehci@101c0000 {
        interrupts = <18>;
    };
 
+   ohci@101c1000 {
+       compatible = "generic-ohci";
+       reg = <0x101c1000 0x1000>;
+
+       phys = <&usb_phy>;
+       phy-names = "usb";
+
+       interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
+       interrupts = <18>;
+   };
+
    ethernet: ethernet@10100000 {
        compatible = "ralink,rt5350-eth";
        reg = <0x10100000 0x10000>;
```

Note address 101c1000 is nowhere mentioned in MT7628 programming manual and it's "one cell away" (0x1000) from standard (and documented) EHCI controller cell (at 101c0000).

I assume similar situation is also true for other SoCs because USB standard mandates to "hand over" low speed devices to a legacy USB1 controller.

I hope this will spare a lot of headache to whoever will stumble in the same problem.